# How to send file have the proxies

Tags: python, selenium

thats my code but didnt work

```
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = open('proziess.txt', 'r').readlines()
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: `prox.http_proxy = open('proziess.txt', 'r').readlines()`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"? See [ask].